# UIPageViewController within UINavigationController, NavigationBar behaves not correct

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I have a uinavigationcontroller where i push a UIPageViewController with UIViewController1, UIViewcontroller2, ....!
I want to have the Navigationbar on UIViewController1, but not on the other UIViewController.
So on the first UIViewController1 i would have:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

and on the other UIViewController2, UIViewController3, ....

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController YES animated:NO];
}
```

Everything works fine when i move forward! But if i am sliding backward after moving from UIViewController3 to UIViewController2, suddenly the navigationBar already apperas on UIViewController2. I guess UIViewController1 is already appearing while i am looking on UIViewController2 and suddenly it gets the notification to show the UINavigationBar.

Putting the Commands into UINavigationBarDidAppear does not solve the problem :-(
Can Somebody help me out?

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer. Actually everything works fine. I was just fooled by my Spaghetti Code i guess.

I didn't notice i already was hiding the navigationbar in the loadview method and then again in the viewWillAppear method. After removing the one in loadView its working perfectly!